# Best strategy for sending digital signal over ultrasound

Tags: digital-communications

I'm interested in sending digital data over ultrasound.

My initial thought is that it should be first converted to BMC:

[image]

And then phase shift encoded (PSK):

[image]

I initially thought to use a Goertzel filter to decode it, but this runs into trouble: [Extracting phase using Goertzel filter in Python](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/15000/extracting-phase-using-goertzel-filter-in-python)

What would be a practical mechanism?

Is there a more intelligent way to encode the data, maybe using two frequencies and taking the relative strength at any moment in time?

Comment: Just a basic question: Why do you use BMC if you use PSK? Since you use PSK, a DC component is obviously no issue. What would be the disadvantage of using PSK right away?

Comment: Without additional info, I would suggest that to simplify things you consider using a scheme like Bell 202 does: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_202_modem

Comment: A good strategy will depend greatly on channel characteristics, such as S/N, bandwidth, multipath distortion, fading, and etc. as well as the data rate.

Comment: Multipath distortion, I take it this is echoes as the sound bounces off objects.  I hadn't thought of this!  This could really mess up any kind of phase shifting approach...

Comment: Multipath interference can also put a deep notch right at your audio carrier frequency.